# How to connect to mongo, using ruby that have credentials?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am trying to connect to a database that has credentials. I cannot find any useful information online...

```
require: 'mongo'

begin
   db = Mongo::Connection.new(" IP ADDRESS " , PORT ).db("COLLECTION")
   db.authenticate("username","password")


rescue StandardError => err
    abort("error")
end
```

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.8.2/lib/mongo/networking.rb:306:in `rescue in receive_message_on_socket': Operation failed with the following exception: end of file reached (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)

Comment: The current [MongoDB Ruby driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver) is version 2.4.3, please upgrade your driver version when you're able to. This should remove your `end of file reached` error message.

Answer (score 1):

looks like there is an [`#add_auth`](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/1.8.2/Mongo/MongoClient.html#add_auth-instance_method) method as well as `auths` can be passed to the constructor maybe try

```
auths = [{"db_name" => "COLLECTION", 
          "username" => YOUR_USERNAME, 
          "password" => YOUR_PASSWORD}]
Mongo::Connection.new(" IP ADDRESS " , PORT, auths: auths)
```

OR

```
auth = {"db_name" => "COLLECTION", 
          "username" => YOUR_USERNAME, 
          "password" => YOUR_PASSWORD}
Mongo::Connection.new(" IP ADDRESS " , PORT).add_auth(auth)
```

and see if that works

Reference [Mongo::MongoClient::GENERIC_OPTS](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/1.8.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb#L37) and [Mongo::MongoClient#setup](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/1.8.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb#L601)

BTW that is a old version of the gem and ruby for that matter. have you considered the possibly upgrading?

Newest version (as of now) of Mongo is 2.4.3 and the options are more transparent now e.g.

```
Mongo::Client.new("IP_ADDRESS:PORT", user: USERNAME, password: PASSWORD, auth_mech: AUTHENTICATION_MECHANISM)
```

Although based on your comments I am not sure authentication is your issue

Comment: Do you think that the gem and ruby version dont work with the mongo client?

Comment: @DarthSid no I am just mentioning it because it looks like the most recent version of the gem is `2.4.3` and ruby's current stable is `2.4.1` (1.9.3 support ended in February of 2015)

Comment: @engineersmknky neither of those worked, same error message.

Comment: @DarthSid not sure "authentication" is your issue then.